# Could not open ServletContext resource running a SpringBoot Junit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I have a SpringBoot app.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class ElPozoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ElPozoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

with this config class inside the config package

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("granjas.properties")
public class GranjasConfig {
..
}
```

and when I run this test

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ElPozoApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ProdPersistenceConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ControlesServiceTests { }
```

I got this error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/granjas.properties]

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using just the @SpringBootTest annotation?  It should be able to find your nested Configuration appropriately.  I'm afraid by using the classes attribute and @ContextConfiguration annotation it might be ignoring your nested Configuration.  i.e,

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ControlesServiceTests { }
```